# avro default value for boolean not applied

Tags: java, boolean, default, avro

I have this avro schema in which I have **capture** declared as boolean and I wanted to give default value as `true`.

```
{
    "namespace": "abc",
    "type": "record",
    "name": "Request",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "amount",
            "type": "long",
        },
        {
            "name": "currency",
            "type": ["string", "null"],
        },
        {
            "name": "capture",
            "type": "boolean",
            "default": true
        } 
}
```

When this is used in Java, it gets default value `null`.
What do I need to do to default it to `true`?

Answer (score 5):

This is not just related to Java. 
In general ( as per documentation available at https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html ) we have:

```
default: A default value for this field, used when reading instances that lack this field (optional)
```

So the default value is used only on schema evolution and so when you read/write records using different schemas. 
For example suppose you want to read a record written with schema A1 using instead the evolved schema A2 and that the **capture** field and has been introduced with schema A2 ( so it didn't exist at schema A1 ).
So the record you get reading contains the default value of schema A2 for that variable.

---

To test I've produced two **Java** classes from a schema respectively with a boolean field with default value as "true" and "false". Generated classes are **identical** except for Avro schema definition. This confirm that default value is not reflected on source code.

I've also tried with **Golang** and the result is the same.